# Why does increasing the load on the secondary coil circuit increase the current in the primary coil circuit

Tags: transformer

"Why does increasing the load on the secondary coil circuit increase the current in the primary coil circuit"

This question is given as an exercise in my book. I can't figure out whether this is a poorly worded question or if I misunderstand. The answer I can come up with is that power is dissipated over the load so more power is needed to be supplied by the ac source. This seems too hand-wavy to me though, why would it not increase in the first place? How could it know that there is an increase in power needed if there was no change in current or magnetic flux from the secondary side to signify the change? Surely the component would just have a smaller potential drop?

Comment: If the voltage stays the same, an increase in the load means an increase in current from the secondary.

Comment: @jamie I've closed your question down because it is a clear duplicate of what's been asked before. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494373/transformer-how-the-primary-current-is-adjusted-to-be-equal-to-the-secondary-lo/494407#494407) is my answer to that question.