# Transformer Secondary Discontinuity

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, magnetics, physics, current-transformer

I am using a step up transformer and I am getting a weird discontinuity in the secondary output. Has anyone seen anything like this before? I cant figure out what might cause this. In a one test setup I can get a nice sinusoidal waveform with the same input voltage when I have a large resistive load (500ohms) on the secondary. When I hook up to this inductive load (5ohms esr) I am getting the weird waveform. Is it possible the output impedance of the transformer is too high for the lower impedance load? Thank you for any insights.

[image]

Dark Blue: Primary Current, Light Blue: Secondary Current, Pink: Secondary Voltage, Green: Primary Voltage

Comment: Looks like saturation.  Do you have a spec sheet for the transformer?

Comment: I wound it myself. Based on my calculations I should have plenty of headroom before saturation with the volt seconds I am applying. Furthermore I am observing the same issue across a range of input voltages on the primary. The waveform stays pretty much the same although the amplitude changes. At the lower input voltages I would not be anywhere close to saturation.

Comment: Is your load inductor air core or iron core? Gapped or not gapped?

Comment: The load inductor is iron core, not sure about the gap. I believe that I am not saturating the load inductor because I can apply more volt seconds to the load inductor with a power supply without saturating it and I am getting nice wave forms with just the power supply connected to the load inductor.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the inductor Not saturating, rather, the load seems to go to a higher impedance state at zero crossing. Perhaps indicative of a gap closing on each cycle (resulting in a higher impedance). I could imagine the core vibrating at frequency, alternating a very small gap and closed gap.  Note the secondary volts increasing , indicating higher impedance load.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea. I would think that would happen the same if I drove it with a power supply but maybe not? I wonder if that could also be happening in my transformer that I wound, the vibration could be causing a change in the gap, which should ideally be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I do not suspect transformer core saturation. At a fixed input voltage to a transformer, you can short circuit the secondary, and the transformer core will not saturate. So, if your core does not saturate with open circuit secondary, it will not saturate with a load. (Assuming fixed frequency).

I was thinking more along the lines of the inductor load Not saturating, rather, the load seems to go to a higher impedance state at zero crossing. Perhaps indicative of a gap closing on each cycle (resulting in a higher impedance). I could imagine the core vibrating at frequency, alternating a very small gap and closed gap. Note the secondary volts increasing , indicating higher impedance load.

Edit 1: Regardless of my mentioning inductor gap, I suspect the anomaly is in the load.

Comment: "if your core does not saturate with open circuit secondary, it will not saturate with a load. " did you mean "with **short** circuit secondary" ?

Comment: @muyustan . . yes, with a load including zero ohms short.

Comment: you did not edit and fix it?? I am not sure if you did a mistake but I asked you and you approved me?? confused

Comment: @muyustan is it this you are having problems with: *if your core does not saturate with open circuit secondary, it will not saturate with a load.*?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, I have very limited knowledge on transformers so I am far away from being sure, but, isn't core saturation related to the corrent being passed from the coils? What does it mean if it is not saturetad when secondary is open then it won't saturate for any load? If it is open circuit on secondary, of coruse it don't saturate because no current is being passed. This is why I thought that way. Again, I probably am wrong, but when s/he replied me and said "yes" but did not edit it, I am confused.

Comment: Core saturation has nothing to do with secondary load current and EVERYTHING to do with magnetization current - [read this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494373/transformer-how-the-primary-current-is-adjusted-to-be-equal-to-the-secondary-lo/494407#494407).

Comment: @Andyaka ok, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look closely: -

[image]

I see the positive peak of the primary current at 2.1 graduations and the negative peak at 1.9 graduations. There is DC content and this is likely because when you applied the excitation voltage, you applied it at the zero-crossing point of the waveform and this will produce a standing DC current in the primary. It isn't helped by the inductive load because it will also be subject to an initial voltage waveform that is passing through zero volts and, in turn it will be biased at a DC level.

It is a saturation anomaly as far as I can tell.